# Prove that $\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(yt)}{y}$ Uniformly converges to $t, t \in [0,R], R > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to show that

$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(yt)}{y}
$$

Uniformly converges to $t \in [0,R], R > 0$

The answers show that:

$$
\forall t \in [0,R]: 0 < yt < \delta \Rightarrow |t-\frac{\sin(yt)}{yt}| < \varepsilon
$$

Therefore the converges is uniform.

I dont understand why? The definition of uniformly converges from what i remember says:

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x,y \in I, |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon
$$

How what they did prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is the definition of uniform continuity of the function, without any reference to uniform convergence. Here the issue
is of uniform convergence of a family of functions, parameterised by $t$.
The family $f_t(y)=\frac{\sin(ty)}{ty}$ converges uniformly in $[0,R]$ to $t$ as $y\to 0^+$ if and only if $\lim_{y\to 0^+}\sup_{t\in [0,R]}|f_t(y)-t|=0$, and that follows from the answers' claim.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. It should be
\begin{align}
0<yt<\delta \Rightarrow \left|1-\frac{\sin(yt)}{yt}\right|<\varepsilon\,.
\end{align}
Then we get
\begin{align}
\left|t-\frac{\sin(yt)}{y}\right|=|t|\left|1-\frac{\sin(yt)}{yt}\right|<R\varepsilon\,.
\end{align}